# baseurl in Service layer of zend framework 2

Tags: url, zend-framework2, email-validation, service-layer

i am trying to implement service layer in my application. But i am facing problem while, when i am send mail from service layer to user.

***Problem:***

I am trying to send email confirmation from service layer, which include path of my website like

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/email-confirmation/email/verificationToken">Click Here to verify your account</a>
```

how can i create link in service mail ? I see this the below example in someone's controller, but how can i do this service layer?

```
->setBody("Please, click the link to confirm your registration => " .
                    $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_ORIGIN') .
                    $this->url()->fromRoute('auth-doctrine/default', array(
                        'controller' => 'registration',
                        'action' => 'confirm-email',
                        'id' => $user->getUsrRegistrationToken())));
```

Comment: I don't know, what you mean by "service-layer" here, but in general you need access to Url Controller Plugin or Url View Helper. Give more information about the code where you want to do it. What class is that and how it's created.

Comment: service layer is the only gateway to interact with the application model. I want to implement all business logic in service layer.
i tried this in my controller "$url = $this->url()->fromRoute('user', array('action' => 'accountverification'));" and echo $url and i get this response "/elibrary2/public/user/accountverification" , but i want full url including baseurl of the application

Comment: Model layer is designed to do business logic. Still don't know how it's implemented in your ZF2 project. Show some code, especially that your layer is not a part of framework. If you have acces to Service Locator, you can just get the controller plugins form it.

Comment: How can i get baseurl? i want to create "href" from my controller so user click from his email and redirect to my website

Comment: In your question you showed the code that lets you get url in controller, but you were asking about "service-layer", so I thought these are two different things. Now I don't know what is the question again. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Service Layer is similar to a Model file, then add below lines of code to the Service Layer class file -

```
protected $router;
protected $request;

public function setRouter($router = null) {
    $this->router = $router;
}

public function getRouter() {
    return $this->router;
}

public function setRequest($request = null) {
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function getRequest() {
    return $this->request;
}
```

Now from the Controller class, when your using the Service Layer class, do similar to the following - (It may not be exactly the same but you will get the idea)

Controller Class -

```
$service_layer_classname = new ServiceLayer_ClassName();
$service_layer_classname->setRequest($this->getRequest());
$service_layer_classname->setRouter($this->getEvent()->getRouter());
```

In this way, you can use similar functions to get the Controller based access in the Service Layer Class.

OR

in a short but not-recommended way, you can just pass the whole controller object (i.e. $this) to the Service Layer class and access all the functions.
Obviously it is not a good programming approach.

I hope it helps.

Comment: how can i get $this->getRouter and $this->getRequest() object through service manager? Basically i want to create service layer object through factries.

Comment: If you are referring the "$this->getRequest()" from the "$service_layer_classname->setRequest($this->getRequest());" and want to do the same in the factory (i.e. defined in Module.php) then you can do so as - 

"$router = $sm->get('router');" and 
"$request = $sm->get('request');"

where $sm can be found from 
"'factories' => array('Service_Classname' => function($sm) { .... })"

Comment: Thank you for helping me. You are really Helpful. I have sevral more questions regarding ZF2, how can i contact?

Comment: @Aneeq, glad to know that it was helpful. You could just add your queries on Stackoverflow so that others (in future) could know about such issues and if anyone knows the answer to it then they could reply more quickly.

Comment: Actually my Question is not a problem, i just wonder how you know that by calling "$sm->get('request')" we get request object. Before you help me i am trying to fetch object by name space like this "$sm->get('name space of file)". Butt didn't work. Is there any list where i can find which service are available in which file?

Comment: At least I haven't found any such list yet. As for, how I knew about it, then it must be one of the SO queries. The requirement was to know which controller / action is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$prefix = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
$server_name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$url = $this->getEvent()->getRouter()->assemble(
              array(
                  'controller' => 'registration',
                  'action' => 'confirm-email',
                  'id' => $user->getUsrRegistrationToken()
              ),
              array('name' => 'ROUTE_NAME')
       );

/*PLEASE REPLACE THE above 'ROUTE_NAME' WITH THE ONE YOU MUST HAVE USED FOR 'registration' CONTROLLER*/

$full_url = $prefix . "://" . $server_name . $url;

->setBody("Please, click the link to confirm your registration => " .
                $this->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_ORIGIN') .
                $full_url
                );

Note: Try echoing the $full_url variable if required.
```

Comment: how i can do this in service layer? In service layer "->getRoute or ->getRequest" is not available.

Comment: It would be really helpful, if you could let us know more about your  "Service Layer". As in, how you have implemented it in ZF2? Where is this file located? What exactly is in this file? and how is it accessed via the controller? Only then we could know, why you cannot access the "->getRoute or ->getRequest".

Comment: I have added a answer just in case your Service Layer is implemented similar to a Model Class or Service Class in ZF2.